# Find frequently visited area from given set of GPS points

Tags: javascript, mongodb, google-maps

I am having a data set of say 10000 GPS points. I need to find GPS points depending on how frequently the area is visited by using the GPS data set I have. I am looking for a solution either by using google maps or by using mongoDB, but unable to find any clue how should I achieve this. Can anyone help me regarding this?

sample data =  `[{18.5204303,73.8567437},{18.520457, 73.856697},{18.520400, 73.856800},{18.520156, 73.857092},{18.519879, 73.857561}]`

Out of the given data set first three point are near to each other.
So, whenever I will ask for frequently visited area from the given data set I should get result as `[{18.5204303,73.8567437},{18.520457, 73.856697},{18.520400, 73.856800},{18.520156, 73.857092}]`

Comment: This is way to broad a question. If you can re-present it in terms of a small sample of data and the result you want to achieve then it becomes something that can be answered. Also what you are generally asking is covering way to many parts. I would suggest breaking this up into at least the "analysis of the data" first, and then separately question about presentation components after you have worked out how to get the general data results you need.

Comment: @NeilLunn thanks for the feedback, I edited contents accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution using google heatmap. I just passed array of gps points to heatmap and the heatmap displayed it in proportion of frequent access to the locations. That is what I was trying to achieve